# Workflow for PHP website development with multiple developers & designers

Tags: php, html, git, svn, netbeans

I thought this had to be a common problem, but I was not able to find an easy solution. The problem is, we are working with multiple people on developing a website, without any version control involved. Which leads to obvious problems with conflicting edits and someone messing up the whole site with no simple way to recover. Currently some work with Filezila + Notepad++ directly downloading, additing and uploading the files.
Others work with Netbeans on their local copy and upload the files automatically when saving.

What I would like to do now is intruduce a version control system that still lets everyone work on the live system, but checks for conflicts and allows to rollback files to previous versions.

I tried to set up GIT with a post-receive hook that copies everything to the webroot, but failed in doing so. Besides I think SVN might be a better solution because everyone has just to checkout/commit instead of pull/commit/push.

- Is it possible to set up GIT/SVN the way I like to?
- Is there a better solution?

Comment: why did you fail to install the hook? what do you expect the answer would be?

Comment: Why do you think having a combined commit/push step is a good thing?

Comment: Don't work on the live site directly. Never. Even with a VCS as middle man. Adopt a proper development, commit, staging, testing, deployment workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an SVN server setup and a cron job on the dev server to pull the latest revision out every 60 seconds.  Then I have another script on the live server that isn't croned but I can manually run which updates the live server to the specified revision when I request it.

This allows the devs to commit and automatically test on the dev server pretty much real time and then when we've reviewed the code changes etc on the dev server and we're happy with it then I manually run the update on the live server.

Answer (score 0):

The "common" problems come from you letting them work on live website ...
A developer on live will always find a way to ruin your day!